# Rename-Item registry key from pipeline adds a space

Tags: registry, key, pipe, rename

I'm just learning Powershell so this should be simple for some of you...

I have the followinng command to rename multiple registry subkeys:

**Get-Childitem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCMINV\OfficeAddins\Addins -Name -Recurse |  % { rename-item $_ "HKLM_ $_" }**

The problem is that the new key name results in a space between the string text and pipeline input, such as:

**"HKLM_(space)Search.OutlookToolbar"**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as posted, DOES include a space between 'HLKM_' and '$_'

`{ rename-item $_ "HKLM_ $_" }`

If this IS just a typo, you could use the following code, which trims any spaces from `$_` prior to inserting it into the string to replace the `{0}` token.

`{ rename-item $_ ( "HKLM_{0}" -f $_.Trim() ) }`

Comment: You're a genius... I acually had looked at the trim and format option, but couldn't figure out how to use them. Live and learn.

Thanks for the help